# Resolving "undefined reference" on pure virtual destructor of base class

Tags: c++, oop, destructor, virtual-destructor

I am learning Object Oriented programming.  Here is a simple code snippet that I have written:

```cpp
class Food {
protected:
    int id;
    FoodTypes type;
    string name;

public:
    Food(int id, FoodTypes type, string name) {
        this->id=id;
        this->type=type;
        this->name=name;
    }
    virtual ~Food() = 0;
};

class Dish: public Food {
protected:
    double cost;

public:
    Dish(int id, FoodTypes type, string name, double cost) : Food(id, type, name) {
        this->cost=cost;
    }
    void display() {
        cout<<id<<" "<<type<<" "<<name<<" "<<cost<<"\n";
    }
    ~Dish() {}
};
```

I get the error:

> /tmp/ccW3e3PZ.o: In function 'Dish::~Dish()':
> main.cpp:(.text._ZN4DishD2Ev[_ZN4DishD5Ev]+0x25): undefined reference to 'Food::~Food()'

Based on the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444800/undefined-reference-to-virtual-base-class-destructor), I need to *define* the destructor of my base class (`~Food`), but IMO I cannot do that since I need it to be a `pure virtual` function (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977138/can-a-c-class-without-any-pure-virtual-methods-be-considered-abstract/)).  If not for the destructor, there's no other function within the base class that can be delegated to be `pure virtual` (and the base class would no longer be abstract/interface).

So how do I resolve the error?  Thanks!

Comment: Your second link shows how to define a pure virtual destructor.

Comment: Pretty sure you could do `virtual ~Food() = default;`

Comment: @fabian, oh, I see, we cannot use `=0;` for declaring a pure virtual destructor of a base class (we need to actually define it with an empty body instead).  Am I correct?

Comment: `pure virtual` doesn't mean it _doesn't_ have an implementation. All pure virtual functions _can_ have an implementation. Additionally a `pure virtual destructor` *must* have an implementation.

Comment: `Food` still needs to be destructed (to destroy it's members), if its destructor was pure virtual it never could be